# How to disable the product price for all the pages in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.3

**from everywhere I need to hide the price if the module is enabled.**

> how can I achieve this functionality? Is anyone have any idea about
>   it?

Comment: Hello, I have an idea about this thing if you want then I develope the extension for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, please develop and share the code. it's very helpful for me.